# argparse not handling abbreviations in subparser properly

Tags: python, argparse, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, subparsers

(Run on **python 3.6.0**)

### **TL;DR**

```
Usage: prog.py {caesar | vigenere} [key]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subp = parser.add_subparsers()
caesar = subp.add_parser("caesar", aliases=["c"], allow_abbrev=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
$ python prog.py caes 123
prog.py: error: invalid choice: 'caes' (choose from 'caesar', 'c')
```

Why is the `subparser` abbreviation invalid even with `allow_abbrev=True`?

---

### **LONG VER**

Basically, having an issue getting `argparse` to accept abbreviated `subparsers` names/aliases.

Here's the code:

```
Usage: prog.py [caesar] [key]

import sys, argparse

def main(argv):
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser
         (description="runs text through X cipher")
subp = parser.add_subparsers\
         (help="sub-command help")

#<ArgumentParser object>
caesar = subp.add_parser\
         ("caesar", aliases=["c"], allow_abbrev=True)
caesar.add_argument\
         ("key", metavar = "key (any integer)",\
          type = int, default = 0)


args = parser.parse_args()
print(caesar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
sys.argv = list(str(c).lower() for c in sys.argv[0:])
main(sys.argv)
```

So from the code above, it should be expected that any of the following should be accepted:

```
- "Caesar" or "caesar"
- "C" or "c" 
- Any abbreviation in between "c" and "caesar"
```

So here's the problem:

This works: `$ python prog.py c 123` O

This gives an error: `$ python prog.py caes 123` X

```
prog.py: error: invalid choice: 'cae' (choose from 'caesar', 'c')
```

Now here's the confusing part.

According to the **argparse doc**:

> ArgumentParser supports the creation of such sub-commands with the
>   add_subparsers() method. The add_subparsers() method is normally
>   called with no arguments and returns a special action object. This
>   object has a single method, **add_parser()**, which takes a command name
>   and any ArgumentParser constructor arguments, and **returns an
>   ArgumentParser object** that can be modified as usual.

1. okay, so any `object created with add_subparser()` can create its own `ArgumentParser object`with `object.add_parser()` right?
2. ...which means this newly created `ArgumentParser` object should be able to accept any `ArgumentParser` arguments yeah?

**ArgumentParser** definition:

```
class 
argparse.ArgumentParser(
prog=None, usage=None, 
description=None, epilog=None, 
parents=[],formatter_class=argparse.HelpFormatter, 
prefix_chars='-',fromfile_prefix_chars=None, 
argument_default=None,conflict_handler='error', 
add_help=True, allow_abbrev=True)
```

> Create a new **ArgumentParser** object. All parameters should be passed as keyword
>   arguments. Each parameter has its own more detailed description below, but in short
>   they are:
>
> `allow_abbrev` - Allows long options to be abbreviated if the abbreviation is unambiguous.
>
> (default: **True**)
>
> *Changed in version 3.5: allow_abbrev parameter was added.*
>
> *(this was on python 3.6.0)*

---

Thanks in advance, guys

Comment: The abbreviation parameter applies to the  flagged arguments of the parser, not to the names or aliases that invoke the subparser.

Comment: Note that allow_abbrev default is true.  What has really been added with 3.6 is the ability to turn it off.  Earlier versions always accepted abbrev.  But it never applied to argument `choices`, just to the `--foo` like flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A patch to allow abbreviations of the subparser names was implemented, but then withdrawn when it proved to be buggy:

[Issue 12713: allow abbreviation of sub commands by users](https://bugs.python.org/issue12713)

Allowing users to turn off abbreviations for long options is a different issue, handled in

[Issue 14910: argparse: disable abbreviation](https://bugs.python.org/issue14910)

Two different parts of the code.

> allow_abbrev - Allows **long** options to be abbreviated if the abbreviation is unambiguous.

A long option is created with:

```
caesar.add_argument('-f','--foobar')
```

With the default `allow_abbrev` value, this would work with '-f', '--foo', and '--foobar'.  The `long_option` in this case is '--foobar'.  With it `False`, '--foo' would not work.

It's the main `parser` that decides whether `c` or `caesar` or `cae` are valid subparser commands (via `subp`, the *special action object* created by `parser.add_subparsers`).  This behaves more like a positional with `choices`.

```
parser.add_argument('foo', choices = ['c', 'caesar'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! This definitely beats trying to figure out the doc.

Answer (score 1):

The error I'm getting is this:

```
usage: [-h] {caesar,c} ...
: error: unrecognized arguments: a e s
```

Hinting that abbreviations are supposed to be composable in the sense that two different abbreviations "c" and "a" can be referenced by passing `ca`.

What is it that should really happen there? `ca` is both a combination between the `c` and the (non-existing) `a` short form, as well as an abbreviation. Which should the parser prefer? Therefore this question had to be resolved explicitly when the library was designed: For predictability, you just cannot have both.

That being said, maybe you can tweak the result by passing `conflict_handler='resolve'`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#allow-abbrev

Comment: What are you giving the parser?  `parser.parse_args(list('caes'])`?  Looks like the `argv` list is `['c','a','e','s']`.

Comment: actually, I was talking about `parser.parse_args(["caes"])`. The thing here is that it should be possible to combine short command line flags. Exactly the same as with POSIX `getopt.h`, think `tr -cd`, `grep -vERF`, or the famous `tar xvzf`.

Comment: Short options can be combined, as in `python prog.py -caes`.  But this does not apply to subparser commands. Only one 'word' works.